# Generic type error: Instance cannot be converted to its own type?

Tags: java, generics

I am receiving a compiler error from the following code segment.  The error occurs at the indicated line:

```
static abstract class AbstractRoot<R extends Root<R>> implements Root<R> {

    private final Map<Grouping, Phrase> m_ph;

    AbstractSqlRoot() { this.m_ph = new HashMap<>(); }

    @Override public PhraseBuilder<R>    phrase() { 
        PhraseBuilder<R> fr = (PhraseBuilder<R>) m_ph.get(Grouping.PHRASE);
        if (fr == null) {
-->         fr = new PhraseBuilder<R>(this);
            m_ph.put(Grouping.PHRASE, fr);
        }
        return fr; 
    }
```

The HashMap `m_ph`is a kind of typesafe heterogenous container.  The type linkage is provided by the `Grouping` enum class, and so the cast that is present in the code is safe.

The class definition for the PhraseBuilder (and its own AbstractPhraseBuilder) follow in the section below:

```
public static abstract class AbstractPhrase<R extends Root<R>> implements Phrase {

    private final List<Element>     m_elem;
    private final R                 m_root;

    AbstractPhrase(R r) 
            { m_elem = new ArrayList<>();  m_root = r; }
    :
    :
}


public static final class PhraseBuilder<R extends Root<R>> extends AbstractPhrase<R> {

    public PhraseBuilder()          { this(null);  }
    public PhraseBuilder(R r)       { super(r); }
    :
    :
}
```

The compiler reports "Incompatible types: `AbstractRoot<R>` cannot be converted to R where R is a type variable: `R extends Root<R>` declared in class `AbstractRoot`."

I am confused.  `AbstractRoot` is declared to implement `Root<R>`, so it should be compatible with a parameter that is defined for "extends `Root<R>`".  I do not see a conflict between the indicated constructor invocation and the class definitions.

Anybody able to help me with this dilemma?  I'm stuck.

---

**UPDATE:** Thanks to the answers given below, I get where I went wrong.  The design of the `SqlRoot<R>` interface really, really requires that an `R` be sent to the `PhraseBuilder` class.  The code has been patched as follows to solve this problem:

```
static abstract class AbstractRoot<R extends Root<R>> implements Root<R> {

    private final Map<Grouping, Phrase> m_ph;

    AbstractSqlRoot() { this.m_ph = new HashMap<>(); }

    @Override public PhraseBuilder<R>    phrase() { 
        PhraseBuilder<R> fr = (PhraseBuilder<R>) m_ph.get(Grouping.PHRASE);
        if (fr == null) {
-->         fr = new PhraseBuilder<R>(typedThis());
            m_ph.put(Grouping.PHRASE, fr);
        }
        return fr; 
    }
    :
    :
    protected abstract R typedThis();
}
```

The class definition for the subclass `ConcreteRoot` now includes a method declaration for `typedThis()`.  Not an ideal solution since the method becomes part of the class's exported API, but it solves the problem:

```
static final class ConcreteRoot extends AbstractRoot<ConcreteRoot> {

    ConcreteRoot() { super(); }

    @Override protected ConcreteRoot typedThis() { return this; }
    :
    :
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `this` is a `Root<R>`, not necessarily an `R`.  Sound confusing?  It is.  Here's a counterexample where it would break:

```
public class MyRootA extends AbstractRoot<MyRootA> {
    //R is MyRootA - "this" is an instance of R
}

public class MyRootB extends AbstractRoot<MyRootA> {
   //R is MyRootA - "this" is NOT an instance of R
}
```

In other words, there's nothing that says that `R` is the same type as `this`.

Self-typing like this is often counterproductive.  It's usually sufficient to just use the more generic type `Root<R>`.  If you really want this, one trick is to obtain a reference to `this` indirectly:

```
 fr = new PhraseBuilder<R>(this.typedThis());
```

Where in `Root<R>` you declare:

```
 R typedThis();
```

and the implementation at the concrete class will normally just be:

```
 public MyRootA typedThis() {
    return this;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Unfortunately, when I designed the API for this stuff I really, really needed methods in the interface `SqlRoot<R>` to return an `R`.  I see where I went wrong.  The solution of getting an `R` from the subclass leaves a visible wart on the API (this class isn't part of an exported API anyway) but it allows me to move on. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`new PhraseBuilder<R>(this)` is trying to invoke this constructor:

```
public PhraseBuilder(R r)       { super(r); }
```

The problem is that `this` is not an `R`: it's an `AbstractRoot<R>`, which also happens to be a `Root<R>`, but it's simply not an `R`. Perhaps you meant this?

```
fr = new PhraseBuilder<Root<R>>(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear, helpful, useful answer.  I see now where I went wrong.  When I designed this API, I really needed methods in interface `SqlRoot<R>` to return an R.  There's just no way around it without refactoring a huge amount of code.  For this reason `new PhraseBuilder<Root<R>>(this)` can't help me.  I really need an `R`.